# Prove that K is a subgroup of $N_G(H)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group, $H$ and $K$ subgroups of $G$ with $H$ a normal subgroup of $K$. The normalizer of $H$ in $G$ is $$N_G(H)=\{g\in G | gHg^{-1}=H\}.$$ Prove that K is a subgroup of $N_G(H)$.

Since $H$ is normal in $K$, then  $gHg^{-1}\in K$.  Does this fact help me?  How can I prove it's a subgroup of the normalizer of H in G?  Need a plan for this proof.

Comment: Let $k \in K$.  Where is $kHk^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know $K$ and $N_G(H)$ are both subgroups of $G$, so all you need to do is to show that $K \subseteq N_G(H)$.  If $k\in K$, then since $H$ is normal in $K$, we have $kHk^{-1}=H$.  This is exactly what needs to be true for $k\in N_G(H)$.

Comment: What do I need to do to show $K\subseteq N_G(H)$? $kHk^{-1}\in H$?

Comment: You take a $k$ from the set $K$ and show that it is in $N_G(H)$.  This is exactly what I did above is prove $K \subseteq N_G(H)$.